# Leaving Stack Exchange Community

Tags: discussion

I've debated for a while whether or not to post this, but I've finally decided now that enough is enough.  The direction that Stack Exchange has been going in is bad enough, but the treatment of certain moderators here is just appalling.  I love the community here, but I just can't stomach to be associated with the flawed for profit company that runs it.

Therefore, I'm taking this opportunity to announce that I'll be quitting from Workplace Stack Exchange.  It's been a fun ride, and I want to say thank you to the vibrant community that has made this such a great site.  And I want to say a special thanks to the moderators who work tirelessly day in and day out.

Take care.

---

**Update**

Thank you for the kind words, SemiColon.  And thank you for the all of those who sent me personal e-mails and texts.

After sitting on it for a few days, and after getting a message from a very prominent member of this community that I respect a lot, I've realized that I may have been a little bit too hasty in my departure.  I've realized that my whole goal of leaving is to try to punish Stack Exchange, but I'm really just hurting myself and hurting the community here.

So with that, I've decided to not leave Stack Exchange after all.  Thanks all for the encouragement!

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334551/an-apology-to-our-community-and-next-steps?cb=1) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334689/where-do-we-go-from-here)?

Comment: I don't think he has, now that he has left.

Comment: Welcome back !!

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you are a regular user, and posting under a different account, as this one has virtually no activity.

If that's the case, could you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

You have never asked or answered a single question.... you'll be sorely missed, good luck on your journey.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere yes I noticed after the fact but too lazy to edit, doesn't matter, the chaps gone anyway

Answer (score -2):

Your contributions were great to the community and I am sorry to see you go as a long time lurker. This site would be bare without you. Thanks again!

Comment: Just curious - which contributions were great? I may be missing something, but I see only a single answer.